# How to simplify $\sqrt[3]{a+\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{a-\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}$?

Tags: roots, radicals, nested-radicals

How to simplify this? 
$$\sqrt[3]{a+\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{a-\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}$$

Comment: You can use MathJax to write equations in your questions; see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Raise it to the third power.

Comment: Use the fact that $a^3+ b^3= (a+ b)(a^2- ab+ b^2)$

Answer (score 2):

$s=\sqrt[3]{a+\frac{a+1}3\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}3}}=\sqrt[3]{a+b}$

$t=\sqrt[3]{a-\frac{a+1}3\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}3}}=\sqrt[3]{a-b}$

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid]{s^3+t^3=2a}$

$\displaystyle (st)^3=(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2=a^2-\frac{(a+1)^2(8a-1)}{27}=-\frac {(2a-1)^3}{27}$

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid]{-3st=(2a-1)j^k}\quad$ with $j^3=1$ and $k=0,1,2$

$(s+t)^3=(s^3+3s^2t+3st^2+t^3)=(s^3+t^3)+3st(s+t)$

So if we set $X=s+t$ then $X$ is solution of $X^3-3stX-(s^3+t^3)=0$

$\bbox[5px,border:1px solid]{X^3+(2a-1)j^kX-2a=0}$

The case $k=0$ is simple :

$X^3-X+2a(X-1)=X(X-1)(X+1)+2a(X-1)=(X-1)(X^2+X+2a)=0$

$X=1$ or $\displaystyle X=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-8a}}2$

According to the graph in real values:

[image]

It seems $X=1$ for $a\in[-1,\frac 12]$ and $X=\frac{-1-\sqrt{1-8x}}2$ for $a<-1$.

However I suspect the grapher to take particular branches of $\sqrt[3]{}$.

In fact among the $9$ possible values for $s+t$ (three roots for $s$ and same for $t$ gives $9$ possibilities for $s+t$), I think that $1,j,j^2$ are always reachable by some combination. 
When trying manually with the help of a CAS, $s,t=(\frac 12\pm x\sqrt{y})j^k$ so this is possible to get $1=\frac 12+\frac 12$ and the other values I get for instance with the green curve above, is just $s+t$ with a $k_s$ and $k_t\neq 0$.

But I have no idea how to present a clean argument for this observation.

Comment: Finally I found it. I let this answer, for people who want some history on how I reach my other solution.

Comment: Hi, you lost me at the part −3st=(2a−1)j^k why do we need j^k. Also how did you come up with solving this lol? Is there like a formula or rule or something I haven't yet come across. By the way I am only still in high school.

Comment: This is the same than when we have $x^2=c^2$ we can say $x=\pm c$. Here $x^3=c^3$ leads to $x=c$ or $x=cj$ or $x=cj^2$ where $j$ is a third root of unity. But this answer is incomplete, you'd better have a look at the other one.

Comment: is j pretty much the imaginary root and is related to de moivre's theorem ? So for example, imaginary root = 1+2i = j then j^2 is the conjugate as well as the other root so j^3=1? or does it only apply with x^3=1

Comment: In general roots of unity are written $\omega$, thus if $\omega^n=1$ then $\omega=\exp(i\frac {2\pi}{n})$ and $w^k$ for $k=1..n$ are all the other roots. When $n=3$, for historical reason we also use $j=\omega=\exp(i\frac{2\pi}{3})=\frac 12+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$ which verifies $j^3=1$ or $j^2+j+1=0$. So when you solve $x^n=y^n\iff x=\omega^k\,y$ for $\omega$ a n-root of $1$ in the same way that $x^2=y^2\iff x=(-1)^ky$ with $\omega=-1$ is a square root of unity. Here for $x^3=y^3$ we have $x=j^ky$

Answer (score 0):

after the hint above we get
$$\left(\sqrt[3]{a+\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}+\left(\sqrt[3]{a-\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}\right)\right)\left(\left(\sqrt[3]{a+\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}\right)^2-\sqrt[3]{a+\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}\sqrt[3]{a-\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}+\left(\sqrt[3]{a-\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}\right)^2\right)=a+\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}+a-\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}$$
can you simplify this?

Answer (score 0):

$s=\sqrt[3]{a+\frac{a+1}3\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}3}}$

$t=\sqrt[3]{a-\frac{a+1}3\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}3}}$

Let's have $\begin{cases}
\displaystyle X=\frac  12\pm\frac 12\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}3}=x\pm x\sqrt{y}\\\\
\displaystyle x=\frac 12,\quad\displaystyle y=\frac{8a-1}{3}\end{cases}$

$\displaystyle X^3=(x^3\pm 3x^3\sqrt{y}+3x^3y\pm x^3y\sqrt{y})=x^3(3y+1)\pm x^3(3+y)\sqrt{y}$

$\displaystyle X^3=\frac 18(8a)\pm \frac 18\bigg(\frac{9+8a-1}3\bigg)\sqrt{y}=a\pm\frac{a+1}3\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}3}$

Thus the complex roots for $s,t$ are $Xj^k$ with $j^3=1$ and $k=0,1,2$.

Note that if $8a-1<0$ then the complex part of $(s+t)$ which resides in $\sqrt{y}$ cancels if we choose the same $k$ for $s$ and $t$.

In such a case, we have $s+t=2xj^k=j^k$ and for $k=0$ the special value $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid]{s+t=1}$

If we want to be complete there are in fact $9$ possible values :

$\displaystyle X(k,\sigma)=j^k\bigg(\frac  12+\sigma\frac 12\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}3}\ \bigg)$

Then the $9$ values are $\{X(k_1,1)+X(k_2,-1)\mid 0\le k_1,k_2 \le 2\}$

---

Edit: a note on how I found $X$.

I had a doubt on my previous answer, and starting playing with Maple, I figured out that roots of $s,t$ seems to share this form  $(\frac 12\pm x\sqrt{y})j^k$.

So I calculated $(\frac 12+x\sqrt{y})^3$ and by identification I found the constraint $\bbox[5px,border:1px solid]{12xy^2=8a-1}$

From there, I went on redacting this actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$x=\sqrt[3]{a+\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{a-\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}$$
Take the cubic power of both sides
$$x^3=2a - (2a-1)x$$
or
$$(x-1)(x^2+x+2a)=0$$
Thus
$$x=1=\sqrt[3]{a+\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{a-\frac{a+1}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8a-1}{3}}}$$